# Pythonで今日から1年後の月末を求めるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Tags: python

今日から1年後は`dateutil`ライブラリを使って求めることができたのですが、さらにその月末を求める方法が分かりません。
もしご存知の方がいらしたら教えていただけると嬉しいです。よろしくお願いします。

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

dt = date.today() + relativedelta(month=1)
```

Comment: 1年1ヶ月後の月初めの前日ということで、`dt = date.today() + relativedelta(years=1, months=1, day=1, days=-1)` となるかと。

Comment: 月初めの前日という考え方ですね。早速ありがとうございます！

Comment: @metropolis コメントで回答しないでください

Answer (score 1):

(コメントから転載)

1年1ヶ月後の月初めの前日ということで、

```
dt = date.today() + relativedelta(years=1, months=1, day=1, days=-1)
```

となるかと。